# Where is the error?

Tags: php, forms, variables, get

im going to make an algorithm menu with this code on index.php

```
 <?php
$menu=$_GET[menu];
$file=$_GET[file];

if(!isset($menu))
{
    $menu="home";
}
if(($menu=="'")||($menu="-")||($menu="/"))
{
    $menu="home";
}
switch($menu)
{
    case'home':
        $file="isi/home.html";
    break;
    case'profile':
        $file="isi/profile.html";
    break;
    case'gallery':
        $file="isi/lihat_bukutamu.php";
    break;
    case'download':
        $file="isi/lihat_bukutamu.php";
    break;
    case'contact':
        $file="isi/buku_tamu.php";
    break;
}
include"header.php";
include"menu.php";
include"content.php";
include"footer.php";
?>
```

but but when i try this script it show me

> Notice: Use of undefined constant menu - assumed 'menu' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\layout\index.php on line 2
>
> Notice: Undefined index: menu in C:\xampp\htdocs\layout\index.php on
>   line 2
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant file - assumed 'file' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\layout\index.php on line 3
>
> Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\layout\index.php on
>   line 3

this is the menu.php

```
<div id="menu-content">
            <div id="menu">
                <h3 class ="judul_1">Main Menu</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.php?menu=home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.php?menu=profile">Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.php?menu=gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.php?menu=download">Download</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.php?menu=contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

can you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying Constant in array which is not defined. Specify it as string

Change this

```
$menu=$_GET[menu];
$file=$_GET[file];
```

to

```
$menu=$_GET['menu'];
$file=$_GET['file'];
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Ok tell me what's the question

Comment: whether ' and " is different? sorry just that

Comment: @Mhaidarfk Dida They are same

Answer (score 2):

add quotes around your variable, as:

```
$menu=$_GET['menu'];
$file=$_GET['file'];
...
```

Comment: Just 30 sec late to answer

Answer (score 0):

Adding quotes as pointed out in other answers will eliminate notices, but doesn't change how the script work (PHP would add the quotes nevertheless).

You are not doing anything with `$file` variable. I guess you would like to include it somewhere between header and footer.

```
include "header.php";
include "menu.php";
include "content.php";
include $file;
include "footer.php";
```

**CAUTION** I would not recommend passing `file` through GET/POST, as an attacker could make the script include/display arbitrary file from your filesystem if not properly secured.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you are missing quotes in $_GET[menu]. And another thing that you should also use isset or empty always while getting request params.

Example:

```
$menu= !empty($_GET["menu"]) ? $_GET["menu"] : '';
```